# Input not working as specified libgdx java

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a 2d boolean arrray that maps where blocks are(if a coordinate is true, then a block lies there).  I am trying to make it so if you click somewhere it sets that position to false therefor mining the block. My mapgrid has a cell size of 10, therefor if I click at (200, 1000), (20, 100) should be set to false in the grid. Here is how I am trying to accomplish this in my `InputListener`

```
    @Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    tmp.x = screenX;
    tmp.y = (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY);
    tmp.z = 0;
    cam.unproject(tmp);
    grid.manipulateGrid((int)(tmp.x) / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE, (int)(tmp.y) / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE, false);
    System.out.println("Clicked at: (" + tmp.x / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE + ", " + tmp.y / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE +")");
    return false;
}
```

Now this almost works perfectly, however the y origin is still the top left, I thought I was fixing this the way I am initializing tmp.y, any help is extremely appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the tmp.y to change the local coordinates after unprojecting like so

```
    @Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    tmp.x = screenX;
    tmp.y = screenY;
    tmp.z = 0;
    cam.unproject(tmp);
    grid.manipulateGrid((int)(tmp.x) / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE, (int)(tmp.y) / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE, false);
    System.out.println("Clicked at: (" + tmp.x / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE + ", " + (Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - tmp.y) / MapGrid.CELL_SIZE +")");
    return false;
}
```